# SQL Exception not handled in user code

Tags: sql-server, exception, arguments

The following error is occurring when i run my code below. I am running a user registration page with details such as first name, last name, user name, password ect. "ID" is my primary key. Error: "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace WebApplication_Assignment
{
    public partial class User_Registration_WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button_SubmitUserReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write("Your registration is successful");

            string sql = "SELECT * from User_Table where User_Name = @username";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    var userParam = new SqlParameter("username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    userParam.Value = TextBox_UserName.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(userParam);

    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: why is your error logging code commented out?  Let's see the actual exception msg please...Also: Don't concatenate strings: use parameters

Comment: I have errors with the error logging code so removed it to move on with the rest of the code, these are the errors for that:error CS1519: Invalid token 'catch' in class, struct, or interface member declaration, error CS1002: ; expected, error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration, error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.

Comment: Here is the full error when I comment out the error logging code, An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Sullivan'.

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Comment: P.S I do not know how to use parameters, help/advice there if you think the code would be more efficient I would really appreciate!

Comment: Hey Mitch, I have edited the code and hopefully using the parameters correctly for my project. Does it matter that I have username first even though ID is my primary key in the first column of my table?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not using parameters, you have a surname (lastname) that is almost certainly "`O'Sullivan`"  See that single quote; it is causing the TSQL statement to be improperly formed.

If you concatenate strings you run into problems like this and open yourself up to SQL Injection attacks. Always use parameters.

Here's a simple example:

```
string sql = "SELECT * from employee where username = @username";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string")
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    var userParam = new SqlParameter("username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    userParam.Value = txtUsername.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(userParam);

    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

There are numerous references to SQL Injections attacks on SO. Here's one example:

[Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements#7505842)

Comment: yes I was using that surname but removed it and used "osullivan" and still the same error.

Comment: How would I change them into parameters??

Comment: SqlDbType.VarChar, the SqlDBType part of this code is underlined explained that it does not exist in this current context?

Comment: it's questions like these that make me wonder why I bother answering anything on SO....sigh...